# Is it possbile to fetch categories sub catgeories sub sub categories in a single query for a dynamic menu?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have two tables for categories and subcategories

```
       Create table m_category (id int, 
       cat_name varchar(30), 
       constraint pk_catid primary key (id)
       );

       Create table m_item (id int, 
       cat_id int, 
       item_name varchar(30), 
       constraint fk_catid 
       foreign key (cat_id)
       references m_category(id)
       );
```

I want my menu to look like[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd3BY.png).
I hope you get the picture.
The idea I have is to run a query like

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM m_category where id='1';
```

And use such queries to fetch each category and subcategory likewise.

But I want to make the menu completely dynamic and fetch the categories and subcategories in less than 3 queries.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join

```
  $sql="SELECT * 
        FROM m_category 
        INNER JOIN m_item on m_category.id = m_item.fk_catid
        where id='1';";
```

Using PDO
assuming you $dbh is your database connectio handle   (if you use mysqli  there are similar functionalities)

```
$id = 1;

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SSELECT * 
            FROM m_category 
            INNER JOIN m_item on m_category.id = m_item.fk_catid
            where id= :id");
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: But i want the query to be completely dynamic i.e where I don't have to define the id as equal to 1

Comment: You can use a var for assign dinamically  your parent id ..  ..the sintax is  depending by the mysql driver you  are using

Comment: what mean dosen't work ?    .. you have error ?  show me the error message  .. wrong result  .. show the result and the expected  result  ..  .?  show a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..  (text not img)